# How to enable dual boot from 2 disks?

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed the latest Ubuntu on a lenovo laptop with a 128GB SSD on `/dev/sdb`. After the installation, I added a new disk with windows 7 on it. Ubuntu recognizes it as `/dev/sda`. How can I make the lapatop dual boot?

I tried reinstalling grub and also `update-grub` with no success

Thanks

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: Please run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` in a Terminal window. In the editor, make sure the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is set to `10`. Save the file and run `sudo update-grub`. When it finishes, reboot the computer. When you see the purple and white (or black and white) GRUB menu, press `C` in your keyboard. You'll be dropped into a prompt. Run `ls`, then post the output here.

Comment: Also run `sudo os-prober` when in Ubuntu and post the output.

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS, and have you installed both systems in UEFI or both in BIOS boot mode? May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: thanks i do not know the differnce between uefi and bios  i will go and read now   
os-prober gives nothing   c did not give prompt